# Language Switcher with React and Next

Tags: reactjs, typescript, internationalization, i18next, react-i18next

My idea of switching between languages is to click on flag (when clicked, the flag will change as well as the language). I am doing well so far, flag is switching and url path too, but I can not make the switch between translations.

For handling url's I am using build in Next option i18n and for actual language translations I am using react-i18next.

**My i18next file is pretty straight forward:**

```
i18n.use(LanguageDetector)
    .use(initReactI18next)
    .init({
        resources: {
            en: {
                translation: translations_EN_homePage,
            },
            da: {
                translation: translations_DA_homePage,
            },},});
```

**Changing language hook and handleOnclick function:**

```
const [language, setLanguage] = useState('en');

const handleOnclick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setLanguage(e.target.value);
    i18n.changeLanguage(e.target.value);
};
```

**And finally solution for my button = flag**

```
                    <button
                        value={language === 'en' ? 'da' : 'en'}
                        onClick={() => {
                            const locale = router.locale === 'en' ? 'da' : 'en';
                            setCookie(locale);
                            {handleOnclick}
                            router.push(
                                `/${locale}`,
                                `/${locale}`,
                                {locale: false,}}} >
                        {router.locale === 'en' ? (
                            <img
                                src={menuItems.data.body[5].items[0].image.url}/>
                        ) : (
                            <img src={menuItems.data.body[4].items[0].image.url} />
                        )}
                    </button>
```

Why the handleOnclick function is not working ? when I am using just 2 buttons for testing it is working totally fine with translating, so where is it conflicting ?

**Example of working handleOnclick funtion, which I dont want to use:**

```
               <button value="da" onClick={handleOnclick}>
                    Danish
                </button>
                <button value="en" onClick={handleOnclick}>
                    English
                </button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't actually calling `handleOnclick`.  You just have `{handleOnclick}` which doesn't do anything.  You need to call the function.  To do that, your `onClick` callback must take the event `e` so that it can pass it on to `handleOnclick`.  You are also missing an ending parenthesis `)` for `router.push`.

This should work:

```
<button
    value={language === 'en' ? 'da' : 'en'}
    onClick={(e) => {
        const locale = router.locale === 'en' ? 'da' : 'en';
        setCookie(locale);
        handleOnclick(e);
        router.push(
            `/${locale}`,
            `/${locale}`,
            { locale: false, }
        );
    }}
>
    {router.locale === 'en' ? (
        <img src={menuItems.data.body[5].items[0].image.url} />
    ) : (
        <img src={menuItems.data.body[4].items[0].image.url} />
    )}
</button>
```

But it's strange to have some of your logic inline and some in a separate function.  I would move it together.

You don't need to use `e.target.value` since the `value` is derived from `language`.  It looks like you are just toggling between two options.

`e.preventDefault` isn't really needed here either because a button click doesn't have a default event that we need to prevent in the way that a link click or a form submission does.

I am not familiar with the `react-i18next` package so I don't know the types of your `i18n` or `router` variables.  It seems like we don't even need a `language` state in this component since you are getting the language from `router.locale`.

```
const language = router.locale ?? 'en';

const handleOnclick = () => {
    const newLang = language === 'en' ? 'da' : 'en';
    i18n.changeLanguage(newLang);
    setCookie(newLang);
    router.push( // is this correct?
        `/${newLang}`,
        `/${newLang}`,
        { locale: false, }
    );
};

return (
    <button
        onClick={handleOnclick}
    >
        {language === 'en' ? ( // you could combine some logic here
            <img src={menuItems.data.body[5].items[0].image.url} />
        ) : (
            <img src={menuItems.data.body[4].items[0].image.url} />
        )}
    </button>
)
```

Comment: you are very right, I was struggling between 2 logics and I couldn't find the way how to combine them.  I appreciate your explanation, since it made it clear for me. The second option you pointed to, works with bit of a small change. Thank you! It also cleaned my code!

Comment: You can clean it up even further by combining you two img tags.  Outside of the render assign const flagIndex = language === 'en' ? 5 : 4, though I don’t know why you have these seemingly arbitrary numbers as your keys.  And const langString = language === ‘en’ ? ‘English’ : ‘Danish’ if you don’t have that elsewhere.  Maybe you need an isEnglish boolean if you are writing that === ‘en’ check multiple times.  You you can render the flag based on the index <img src={menuItems.data.body[flagIndex].items[0].image.url} alt={‘Language: ‘ + langString} /> add some sort of tooltip or title too.